# Build multiple projects and dependencies into one jar file

Tags: java, maven, docker, jar, package

I want to package in a different way a Java application in order to build the associated Docker image. Basically the current configuration is to build the Docker image based on a folder containing 2 directories :

- prog : JAR files of the Java projects that have dependencies between them
- lib : libraries of the project (dependencies)

What I would like to do is to create a JAR file containing the content of those two folders.

The Java projects are not all dependent, but there is one defining objects that are used in other projects. 
I am currently looking for a way to package all of these projects into one JAR. I found a tool called OneJar that would solve my problem, but I am not sure if this would be the right way..

Do you have some suggestions on the way to proceed ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

With maven:

- The maven Shade plugin will make a single "uber" jar with all your dependencies. https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/index.html
- The spotify docker-maven-plugin will build and push your image with this uber jar: https://github.com/spotify/docker-maven-plugin

You can also look at the google jib project https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib

Comment: Okay thanks, I tried to implement it in the pom of the project used by the other projects. I t generates a JAR file, with its dependencies, but only contains the compiled classes of this project. How could I integrate the other projects in the JAR file ?